# Can't find aggregation result column in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
s = pd.Series(["08-10-2017", "08-10-2017", "08-10-2017", "09-10-2017", "09-10-2017", "09-10-2017", "10-10-2017", "10-10-2017", "10-10-2017", "11-10-2017", "11-10-2017", "11-10-2017", "12-10-2017", "12-10-2017", "12-10-2017", "13-10-2017", "13-10-2017", "13-10-2017", "14-10-2017", "14-10-2017"])
p = pd.DataFrame(data=s)
p.columns = ['date']
p.groupby('date').agg('count').reset_index().columns
```

Where is 'count' column ?

Comment: Can you add the result you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `value_counts`

```
p.date.value_counts()
Out[1095]: 
09-10-2017    3
13-10-2017    3
10-10-2017    3
12-10-2017    3
08-10-2017    3
11-10-2017    3
14-10-2017    2
Name: date, dtype: int64
```

And if you want to do with groupby

```
p.groupby('date').size()
```

And if do want using count

```
p.groupby('date').agg({'date':'count'})
Out[1101]: 
            date
date            
08-10-2017     3
09-10-2017     3
10-10-2017     3
11-10-2017     3
12-10-2017     3
13-10-2017     3
14-10-2017     2
```